# What classes are designed to pair together in lore or class description?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I'm looking for classes that play together, like Thayan Knight and Red Mage.I'm asking about classes which are specifically called in the lore or class descriptions as being paired. Any suggestions?

Comment: This question is far to broad to have any useful answers.  If you can edit it to list your specific requirements - what you intend to do with your character, we may be able to help you build an optimized character.  Take a look at the [tour] and the [help].  Welcome to the RPG Stack Exchange.

Comment: I think the problem is actually that the question is too specific, rather than too broad.  I believe OP is asking about classes which are specifically called in the lore or class descriptions as being paired.  Thayan Knights are specifically an order that serve the Circle of Red Magi as bodyguards, protectors, and partners.  I can't really think of any other classes that are paired like that.

Comment: @gatherer818 Yes, I can think of about a dozen such classes, which falls solidly in the “quite reasonable answer length” category. But I’d like confirmation from the OP that your understanding of the question is correct. As is, the question is fairly vague.

Comment: This is getting better, but can you edit this question to narrow this down a little?  Which setting's lore are you concerned with, for example.  Also, are you interested in only WotC published material?

Comment: Also, are you referring only to official WotC-published sourcebooks? Because if you expand it to all 3rd-party published books or even homebrewed self-published material, this list *will* be endless and unknowable.

Comment: It's still a list question because it has no meaningful stated goal or constraints than "tell me some classes that play together." That's not really a good question.

Comment: Hey @adoptagnome, can you explain the core problem you're trying to solve more? We don't usually like list questions where folks just brainstorm a list of things that fit arbitrary criteria on RPG.SE.  What are you really looking for? What makes one better than another? See http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask for guidance on making questions good for the site.

Comment: " It's still a list question because it has no meaningful stated goal or constraints than "tell me some classes that play together." That's not really a good question. –  mxyzplk♦ yesterday " That comment...is still factually incorrect.